# nextLine() ignoring delimiter "\\n"

Tags: java, delimiter

I am reading input from a file where text is seperated by one or more newlines. To ignore blank newlines I use  `input.useDelimiter("\\n");` But for some reason the nextLine()-method reads the blank lines instead of ignoring them. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Assume that the first line is a blank newline, and the second line has the string `"ABC"`

```
    input.useDelimiter("[\n]+");
    String kjkj = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("***"+kjkj+"***");
```

Gives this result: `******`
Instead of `***ABC***`

Comment: Did you check what `Scanner#nextLine` does?

Comment: @johnchen902 \ char is being escaped.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Oops... Seems like I have to reread the document of Scanner.

Comment: You could just take a line at a time and trim the line.  If the line is empty strings after trim, then you can just skip it.

Comment: Even if line is empty (has nothing beside line separator `\n`) it is still line so `readLine` correctly returns empty String. What you should be interested in is `next` method, not `nextLine`. Also you probably should using `[\n\r]+` as delimiters if you want to ignore empty lines.

Comment: @johnchen902 You have to read the documentation of regular expressions. `\` is not an escape character inside `[]`. No idea why you're using `[]` here at all as you are *trying* to have only one character inside it.

Answer (score 8):

[Scanner#nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)
Does not use the delimiter pattern, it used its own internal one to check for every instance of a new line.

To fix it, use `Scanner#next()` with a delimiter pattern `"\\n+"` to check for multiple new lines in a row.

```
// Change the delimiter to the newline char
// \\r used just for Windows compatibility
input.useDelimiter("[\\r\\n]+");
// Get the next non-blank line
String nextLineThatHasSomething = input.next();
```

Comment: You may use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` to use the current OS line separator.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ... or from Java7 System.lineSeparator()